# I can't register my device in samsung account?

Tags: applications

When I open my android device and open my user details in Samsung I can see registered devices. There is no option to add my device. When we buy a new phone we activate our new device with the sim card. Here what is this registered devices section and how do I register my device. Do I need to go online for device registering?

I want to know how to register my device.

Comment: Please refer to [How to register a Samsung product with your Samsung Account](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00089142/)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you so much. I am able to register my device after entering my sim 2 imei number. Still not showing in phones settings registered devices list. I will update If there is any change.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add your Samsung account to the new device.  Similarly, if you want to see the new device in Google's list, add the Google account to it.

Comment: That is not the issue. I have a Samsung device and when I click settings I can see my Samsung account on top of the settings list. Then I clicked the Samsung account and then I can see the list as Profile info, Devices, Places and so on.... Then I clicked Devices and I can see my device name and all other devices connected to my Samsung account. Now scroll to bottom and see Registered devices in the More section. Click the Registered devices and I can see "No registered devices". How do I add my device details here in the Registered devices section.